# playframework 1.2. insert raw html into template?

Tags: playframework, template-engine

Assume the template consists of only one variable:

> ${htmlString}

and the corresponding Controller:

```
render("<div>some html markup</div>");
```

As a result i get an escaped string, but want to get the original html. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ${mystring.raw()} i think.
Or embed it inside a #{verbatim} tag.
-morten

Answer (score 1):

In the Play2 template engine the escaping is done like this:

```
@Html("\n<br>")
```

([Source](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplates))