# Play framework 1.2.5: Render partial of view with plain html

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a page contains multiple div, one div contains plain html code generated from other web service, how could I render this page?

Here is my code, it does not work, could anyone tell me what's the right way to do it?  Thanks

**controller**

```
public static void demo(String input) {
        String plain_html_code = someWebService.serve(input);
        render(plain_html_code);
    }
```

**demo.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id='Area1'>
    <h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
<div id='Area2'>${plain_html_code}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
I think my problem might be I should use the original value of `plain_html_code` instead of have it escaped, but how can I do it?

Comment: I found the answer [in another question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919256/playframework-1-2-insert-raw-html-into-template

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered?